# I don't know why I can't find useful data with my mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use express framework to find some data in my database(mongodb),I want to find some data match name,author or press,one of them is ok,but I can't get data which I want to.I don't know what?

```
    router.post('/search', function (req, res, next) {
    const {searchContent} = req.body;
    const content = {searchContent};
    var reg = content.searchContent;
    PublishBook.find({
        $or: [{
            name: {$regex: reg, $options: '$i'},
            author: {$regex: reg, $options: '$i'},
            press: {$regex: reg, $options: '$i'}
        }]
    }, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs.id);
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (docs.length <= 0) {
            return res.status(401).send('not find content');
        } else {
            return res.status(201).send(docs.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What response are you getting?

If you're getting a `201` response with `undefined` body, the reason is that `docs` does not have an `id` property because `docs` is always an array.

If you want to get the `id` of the first found document then do:

```
return res.status(201).send(docs[0].id);
```